# How to see if a string ONLY contains a substring in python

Tags: python, substring

I need to be able to see if a string only contains a substring or a letter, and nothing else.

Say I wanted to detect `World`

This would contain the substring but it also has different letters in a different order

```py
"Hello World"
```

This doesn't contain any different lettering or order, just the substring 3 times

```py
"WorldWorldWorld"
```

If I wanted to detect `_`

This wouldn't pass

```py
"Hello_World"
```

But this would

```py
"___"
```

How do I do this?

Comment: have you tried using replace and checking the resulting string length?

Comment: @Chris That worked, I probably should've done more research before posting this question...

Comment: It's all good, the regex answer here is also good

Comment: The problem with using regex is that it's much much slower than string.replace. The replace method should be the answer of this question.

Comment: What output do you expect for substring "WorldWorld" and data "WorldWorldWorld"?

Comment: @wim At least for my case that shouldn't be considered a string with only a substring, since it contains the substring once, and a unique string which is `World`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No regex necessary. Relying on the fact that [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) counts *non-overlapping* occurrences

```
len(target) * data.count(target) == len(data)
```

Simple string methods are 400-800% faster than regex here:

```
>>> import re
>>> target = "World"
>>> data = "World" * 3
>>> pattern = f"^({re.escape(target)})+$"
>>> %timeit len(target) * data.count(target) == len(data)
115 ns ± 0.352 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
>>> %timeit re.match(pattern, data) is not None
456 ns ± 2.88 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
>>> %timeit bool(data.replace(target, ''))  # str.replace is faster again
51.7 ns ± 0.269 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
```

Comment: So cool! I learned something new, thank you. But note that for very long `data` strings that do not match `target` substring close to the beginning, a simple "split + loop" method may be faster, see my Method 2.

Comment: Just curious, Why were 1,000,000 loops done for `re.match` but 10,000,000 loops were done for everything else?

Comment: just because `re.match` turned out to be slower.  [%timeit](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) tries to finish fast enough that you don't have to wait around, so the number of loops is variable/dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression, using `re.escape` to generate a pattern that matches one or more consecutive occurrences of the target (using `^` and `$` to indicate the beginning and end of the string, respectively) as well as `re.match` to determine whether it matches the desired pattern:

```py
import re

target = "World"
data = "World" * 3

pattern = f"^({re.escape(target)})+$"
re.match(pattern, data) is not None
```

This outputs:

```py
True
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

Without regular expressions (regexes), one can simply use [sets](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). First, split the string `s` in question into substrings of the same length as the substring `substr`. Make a set `s_set` out of these substrings. If that set has only 1 element, and that element in `substr`, then print `True`, otherwise `False`.

```
strs = ["WorldWorldWorld", "Hello World"]
substr = "World"
len_substr = len(substr)

for s in strs:
    s_set = set(s[i:(i + len_substr)] for i in range(0, len(s), len_substr))
    print(len(s_set) == 1 and substr in s_set)
# True
# False
```

**Method 2:**

If speed is important, then for very long strings, it makes sense to stop as soon as the first non-matching substring is found, as in this solution:

```
for s in strs:
    only_substr = True
    for i in range(0, len(s), len_substr):
        cur_substr = s[i:(i + len_substr)]
        if cur_substr != substr:
            only_substr = False
            break
    print(only_substr)
# True
# False
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a regular expression.

```
if re.match("(?:World)+", s):
```

This only succeeds if `s` contains one or more repetitions of the string `World`, and nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

This is a job for regular expressions, [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.match).

```py
import re

re.match(r"(?:World)+", "World")
re.match(r"(?:World)+", "Hello World")
re.match(r"(?:World)+", "WorldWorldWorld")
```